# Is there a way to integrate functions by d(logx) instead of dx in python?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, integral

I'm looking for a way to integrate functions in log(x) space. Scipy offers integration but I can't find how to use them in log(x) space.

My integral is

[image: integral]

I tried to substitute log(x) into x and change entire equation, but after integrating in scipy, it shows an error (34, 'Result too large').

Here is my code. Thank you in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand(x,w,x1,t):
    return (1-np.exp(-(t/(10**(x)))))*((w/((x+x1)**2+w**2))/np.pi)

def func(w,x1,t):
    return quad(integrand,0,np.inf,args=(w,x1,t))[0]

t = np.logspace(-8,-2,1000,endpoint = True, base = 10)
vec_func = np.vectorize(func)
y3 = vec_func(0.1,5,t)
```

After using this, error code (34, 'Result too large') shows up.

But if I change the t value to

```
t = np.logspace(-8,-2.5,1000,endpoint = True, base = 10)
```

the error code disappears.

Comment: Please edit the code you already have into the question.

Comment: What should be the resulting value? Have you checked with other software?

Comment: Total value should stay between 0~1. When i run with -2.5, it's far from the float limit in python.